# Can I use a multidimensional array as JWT Token payload?

Tags: php, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I am using JWT Token Authentication with lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle version 2.18.1.
I have an API and my complete user information is stored in the JWT token I get from an external system.
The information is an multidimensional array with the user identifier "uid" being stored in the user.

Example:

```json
{
    "application": {
        "appcode": "my_app"
    },
    "user": {
        "uid": "p320666",
        "firstname": "John",
        "mail": "John.Doe.com",
        "lastname": "Doe"
    },
    "grants": [
        "create"
    ],
    "resources": [
        {
            "code": "foo",
            "values": [
                "5"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateDate": {}
}
```

My user identifier is uid and it is in the 2nd level of my information array.

If I set in my configuration `user_id_claim: user`  I get understandably the warning:
`Array to string conversion` because in JWTAuthenticator.php

```php
        $passport = new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge(
                (string)$payload[$idClaim],
                function ($userIdentifier) use ($payload) {
                    return $this->loadUser($payload, $userIdentifier);
                }
            )
        );
```

it tries to read my user array as a string.

If I set `uid` in my configuration it isn't found. `user.uid` also doesn't work.

Is there an option to access my `uid` information without changing the structure of the payload?

Comment: I'm afraid you won't be able to achieve this with the current state of the code. I think your only option is to propose a change to the bundle and open a PR, or use a forked version.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of. It should work if a copy of the uid value is moved to the 1st level.

Comment: If you can influence the token payload, then this will be the easiest option.

Comment: sure. I talked to the colleague, but he was not agreeable. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now by writing a custom authenticator:

security.yaml

```yaml
security:
  enable_authenticator_manager: true
  providers:
    jwt:
      lexik_jwt:
        class: App\Security\User\User

[...]

  firewalls: # selbstdefinierte Bereiche: dev oder doc können auch abc heißen
[...]
    api:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: true
      jwt:
        authenticator: app.custom_authenticator
```

services.yaml

```yaml
  app.custom_authenticator:
    class: App\Security\Authentication\JwtTokenAuthenticator
    parent: lexik_jwt_authentication.security.jwt_authenticator
```

lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
[...]
  pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%' # required for token creation
  token_ttl: 3600 # token TTL in seconds, defaults to 1 hour
  user_id_claim: user
```

and finally my custom authenticator where I changed the line `(string) $payload[$idClaim]['uid'],` and also call an extra class TokenDataProcessor to extract my complete user info from the payload:

```php
namespace App\Security\Authentication;

[...]

class JwtTokenAuthenticator extends JWTAuthenticator
{
    private JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager;

    public function __construct(
        JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtManager,
        EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher,
        TokenExtractorInterface $tokenExtractor,
        UserProviderInterface $userProvider,
        ?TranslatorInterface $translator = null
    ) {
        $this->jwtManager = $jwtManager;
        parent::__construct($jwtManager, $eventDispatcher, $tokenExtractor, $userProvider, $translator);
    }

[...]

    public function doAuthenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $token = $this->getTokenExtractor()->extract($request);
        if (false === $token) {
            $message = 'Unable to extract a JWT token from the request. Also, make sure to call `supports()`'
                       . ' before `authenticate()` to get a proper client error.';
            throw new LogicException($message);
        }

        try {
            if (!$payload = $this->jwtManager->parse($token)) {
                throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token');
            }
        } catch (JWTDecodeFailureException $e) {
            if (JWTDecodeFailureException::EXPIRED_TOKEN === $e->getReason()) {
                throw new ExpiredTokenException();
            }

            throw new InvalidTokenException('Invalid JWT Token', 0, $e);
        }

        $idClaim = $this->jwtManager->getUserIdClaim();
        if (!isset($payload[$idClaim])) {
            throw new InvalidPayloadException($idClaim);
        }

        $passport = new SelfValidatingPassport(
            new UserBadge(
                (string) $payload[$idClaim]['uid'],
                function ($userIdentifier) use ($payload) {
                    return $this->loadUser($payload, $userIdentifier);
                }
            )
        );

        $passport->setAttribute('payload', $payload);
        $passport->setAttribute('token', $token);

        return $passport;
    }

    public function loadUser(array $payload, string $identity): UserInterface
    {
        try {
            $user = (new TokenDataProcessor())
                ->extract($payload);

            return $user;
        } catch (InvalidAuthDataException $e) {
            $message = 'Authentication Failure with Credentials: ' . json_encode($payload)
                       . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();
            $this->logInfo($message);
            throw new ApiException(401, $message, $e, [], 7020);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
To extract the uid property from the JSON string in PHP, you can decode the JSON string into an associative array using `json_decode()`, and then access the uid property as you would with any associative array. Here's how you can do it:

```
$jsonString = '{
    "application": {
        "appcode": "my_app"
    },
    "user": {
        "uid": "p320666",
        "firstname": "John",
        "mail": "John.Doe.com",
        "lastname": "Doe"
    },
    "grants": [
        "create"
    ],
    "resources": [
        {
            "code": "foo",
            "values": [
                "5"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateDate": {}
}';

// Decode the JSON string into an associative array
$data = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// Access the 'uid' property from the 'user' object
$uid = $data['user']['uid'];

echo $uid; // Output: p320666
```

In this code:

`json_decode($jsonString, true)` decodes the JSON string into an associative array. The second parameter true is used to specify that we want an associative array instead of an object.
We then access the uid property using array notation `($data['user']['uid'])`.
This will give you the value of the uid property from your JSON string.

Comment: Yes, but what would be the proper value in the configuration file? 
The way you describe it I extract the information and convert it into my User object. But I need one marker which is my user identity in my case the uid.